# importando a conexão de um arquivo .py

Tags: python-3.x

Bom dia, uso [peewee](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/quickstart.html#model-definition) com PostgreSQL, funcionando muito bem.

As credenciais de conexão são as seguintes:

```
db = PostgresqlDatabase (
                        'ALTERDATA_WSHOP', # Required by Peewee.
                        user = 'postgres', # Will be passed directly to psycopg2.
                        password = '# abc123 #', # Ditto.
                        host = 'localhost') # Ditto.
```

**Como faço para salvar isso em um arquivo .py e recuperar essas informações, se houver?**

Abaixo do meu código:

```
from datetime import datetime
from peewee import (PostgresqlDatabase, CompositeKey, Model, CharField, DateTimeField, 
               DoubleField, IntegerField, TextField, BooleanField)

def open_config_pg():
    try:
        with open('pg_config.py', 'r') as f:
            # Conteúdo do arquivo
            db = f.read()

    except:
        text = "PostgresqlDatabase('ALTERDATA_WSHOP', user='postgres', password='#abc123#', host='localhost')"

        with open('pg_config.py', 'w') as f:
            # Conteúdo do arquivo
            f.write(text) 

        with open('pg_config.py', 'r') as f:
            # Conteúdo do arquivo
            db = f.read()

return db 

class UnknownField(object):
    def __init__(self, *_, **__): pass


class BaseModel(Model):  

    class Meta:
        db = open_config_pg()
        database = db
```

Meu retorno é este:

**Arquivo "/home/elias/.pyenv/versions/3.8.3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/peewee.py", linha 2150, em _execute cursor = database.execute (self) AttributeError: objeto 'str' não tem atributo 'executar'**

Comment: o return está fora da função.

Comment: É verdade! Mas infelizmente ele retornou mais um erro:

     raise ValueError('Query has not been executed.')
 ValueError: Query has not been executed.

Comment: Veja que o que você está lendo do arquivo é o texto de um programa. Simplesmente ler o texto e retornar não faz com que ele seja executado, é apenas uma string pro Python. Na realidade, você deveria gravar no arquivo os parâmetros da conexão e chamar o código com eles. Uma solução facil é usar json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opa, tente com isso aqui:

```
import json
from datetime import datetime
from peewee import (PostgresqlDatabase, CompositeKey, Model, CharField, DateTimeField, 
                    DoubleField, IntegerField, TextField, BooleanField)


default_ config = {"banco": "ALTERDATA_WSHOP", 
                   "user": "postgres", 
                   "password": "#abc123#",
                   "host": "localhost"}


def save_config_pg(config):
    with open('pg_config.json', 'w') as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(config))


def open_config_pg():
    try:
        with open('pg_config.json', 'r') as f:            
            config = json.loads(f.read())
    except Exception:        
        config = default_config
        save_config_pg(config)
    return PostgresqlDatabase(config["banco"], user=config["user"], password=config["password"], host=config["host"])

class UnknownField(object):
    def __init__(self, *_, **__): pass


class BaseModel(Model):  

    class Meta:
        db = open_config_pg()
        database = db
```

Você pode tentar fazer lendo um arquivo .py, mas é um pouco mais difícil, pois você teria que fazer um import e tratar o erro caso o import não existe. Eu prefiro um arquivo de configuração mesmo.

Com import ficaria assim:

```
from datetime import datetime
from peewee import (PostgresqlDatabase, CompositeKey, Model, CharField, DateTimeField, 
               DoubleField, IntegerField, TextField, BooleanField)

def open_config_pg(n=0):
    try:
        from pg_config import db        
    except ImportError:
        text = """
from peewee import PostgresqlDatabase
db = PostgresqlDatabase('ALTERDATA_WSHOP', user='postgres', password='#abc123#', host='localhost')\n"""
        with open('pg_config.py', 'w') as f:
            # Conteúdo do arquivo
            f.write(text) 
        if n == 1:
            raise
        return open_config_pg(1)
    return db


class UnknownField(object):
    def __init__(self, *_, **__): pass


class BaseModel(Model):  

    class Meta:
        db = open_config_pg()
        database = db
```

Comment: Bom dia meus amigos!
nmenezes, saída perfeita.
Obrigado, funcionou!

Comment: Ainda prefiro a solução com json. Usar um .py para isso pode causar outros problemas, especialmente porque o arquivo teria que estar no import path. Um json pode ser aberto de qualquer lugar e você não corre o risco do usuario escrever algo errado no programa.